# Pass an object from C# to C++ using C++/CLI or convert Object^ to Object

Tags: c#, c++, c++-cli

In C++, I create this class:

```
public ref class UConfig
{
    public:
       UConfig(short nr);
       ~UConfig();
       bool checkNr();

    private:
      short _nr;
}
```

and a public class in C++ that will be called in C#:

```
public ref class UConfigHandler
{
    public:
        UConfigHandler(UConfig^ uConfig);        
}
```

Then in C#, I can do it like this:

```
UConfig uConfig = new UConfig(1);
UConfigHandler uConfigHandler = UConfigHandler(uConfig);
```

in C++, I debug it and I inside the constructor:

```
UConfigHandler::UConfigHandler(UConfig^ uConfig)
{
    // while debugging I see that uConfig is: System::Object^
    // how to do the conversion from the uConfig to UConfig inside C++
    // I would like to do something like this but I got an exception
    UConfig myConfig = uConfig; // the program is stopped here but I dont know what is the error
}
```

So, basically I want to convert the System::Object^ uConfig to the native UConfig. How can I do that?

Something I have done similar with String^ to string:

> input is String^

```
IntPtr stringPointer = (IntPtr)Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(input);

string retrievedString = string((char*)stringPointer.ToPointer());
```

Comment: In the string scenario you are just copying the contents into a local string object.  You can create a method to do the same for UConfig, although I don't know why you need an object on the stack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to assign a handle of a `UConfig` instance to a `UConfig` object. You've declared `UConfig^ uConfig` as a reference, therefore you can only assign it to a reference.

It would be the equivalent in C++ if you did this:

```
MyClass* mcp = new MyClass();
MyClass mcv = mcp;
```

In other words, your `UConfigHandler` constructor should look like this:

```
UConfigHandler::UConfigHandler(UConfig^ uConfig)
{
    UConfig^ myConfig = uConfig;
}
```

### Update

You might be able to do it... you can marshal a `struct` so you should be able to marshal a `class` too. I haven't done that, but the documentation of [Marshal.StructureToPtr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.marshal.structuretoptr.aspx) gives a similar example:

```
// Initialize unmanged memory to hold the struct.
IntPtr pnt = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(uConfig));

// Copy the struct to unmanaged memory.
Marshal.StructureToPtr(uConfig, pnt, false);

// Create another UConfig.
UConfig myConfig ;

// Set this UConfig to the value of the 
// UConfig in unmanaged memory. 
myConfig = (UConfig)Marshal.PtrToStructure(pnt, typeof(UConfig));
```

However, you can no longer take advantage of the garbage collection: you've allocated unmanaged memory so you'll also have to free it! If you don't free the allocated memory you will get a memory leak, so don't roget to do this:

```
// Free the unmanaged memory.
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(pnt);
```

Comment: Can I convert: UConfig myConfig = (convert)uConfig? I just have updated my question with the same thing for: String^ to string

Comment: for this way, I can not access the method: myConfig.checkNr();

Comment: I'm still not sure why you would not want to leave it managed and call myConfig->checkNr()?

Comment: @devn the other thing is that after marshaling the object you'll have to manually free the pointer that you've allocated, if you leave it as a reference you can still taking advantage of the garbage collection and you don't have to clean up after yourself.

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to do? The `UConfig^` you receive in the constructor of `ConfigHandler` is a perfectly valid handle to a `UConfig` .NET instance. There is no need to marshal, cast or do anything special about it.

> So, basically I want to convert the System::Object^ uConfig to the native UConfig. Could you please tell me how can I do it?

**There is no native `UConfig` in the code snippet you've posted.** You create an instance in C# and pass it to the `ConfigHandler` which stores a reference to it:

```
public ref class ConfigHandler {
    Config^ mConfig;
public:
    ConfigHandler(Config^ pConfig) : mConfig(pConfig) {}
};
```

You could even define the `ConfigHandler` in a completely different assembly using C#, there would be no difference. Well almost none, your `ConfigHandler` defined in C++/CLI will implement IDisposable, but since it does not store any unmanaged resources it does not matter. Hm, are you aware of the fact that you are not writing C++ but C++/CLI which is a huge difference?

Comment: you are right. I thought that writing C++/CLI is a huge difference with C++. But I just have found out. It is almost the same. Thanks a lot!